# Maximum value of area of rectangle

Tags: calculus

[image]

Tried  attempting by using altitude and similarity of triangles, 
but the problem is that variables are not getting elliminated.

Comment: In your diagram there are no points labelled B or C.

Comment: @coffeemath It is a typo. The bottom points should be $B,C$.

Comment: General hint for such problems: always find which parameters describe the problem without redundancy and express everything with them. In this case, it is obvious that addition of each rectangle is a 1-dimensional choice. For example, you can choose heights of rectangles as parameters and express their widths from geometry.

Answer (score 1):

By Cavalieri's principle we can make the outer triangle isosceles without changing the rectangles' area. By hyperbolic transformations we can make this triangle have base 6 and height 4, again keeping the rectangle areas intact.

Let $p=P_1S_1$ and $q=P_2S_2$. The triangle area outside the rectangles, which we want to minimise, is
$$p\cdot\frac34p+q\cdot\frac34q+(4-p-q)\cdot\frac34(4-p-q)$$
(The $\frac34$ factors are there because we can rearrange the unoccupied space into three 4:3 rectangles whose longer sides are $p,q,4-p-q$.)
$$=\frac34\left(p^2+q^2+(4-(p+q))^2\right)$$
$$=\frac32(p^2+pq+q^2-4p-4q)+12$$
The gradient of the expression in brackets is $(2p+q-4,2q+p-4)$ and this is zero when $p=q=\frac43$. Thus these are the rectangle heights maximising the area occupied, which is
$$\frac32\left(8\cdot\frac43-3\cdot\frac43\cdot\frac43\right)=8$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $x$ the height from $A$ onto $S_2R_2$, $y=|S_2P_2|$, and $z=|S_1P_1|$. The area of rectangles is then $$A_r=z|S_1R_1|+y|S_2R_2|$$ We can write these segments in terms of $|BC|$ by looking at similar triangles:
$$|S_2R_2|=|BC|\frac{x}{x+y+z}\\|S_1R_1|=|BC|\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}$$
Therefore:
$$A_r=|BC|\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x+y+z}$$
Since $|BC|$ and $x+y+z$ are constant for a given triangle, we want to maximize $xy+yz+zx$ with the constraint that $x+y+z=k$, where $k$ is some constant.
Using Lagrange multiplier method:
$$\partial_x (xy+yz+zx-\lambda(x+y+z-k))=0\\\partial_y (xy+yz+zx-\lambda(x+y+z-k))=0\\\partial_z (xy+yz+zx-\lambda(x+y+z-k))=0$$
you get:
$$y+z-\lambda=0\\x+z-\lambda=0\\x+y-\lambda=0$$
Using $x+y+z=k$, when adding these equations you get$$2k-3\lambda=0$$
or $\lambda=\frac{2}{3}k$. The solution is $$x=y=z=\frac{k}{3}$$
Then $$\max(A_r)=\frac{3(k/3)^2}{k}|BC|=\frac{k|BC|}{3}$$
Notice that $k|BC|$ is twice the area of the triangle, so $$\max(A_r)=8$$

Comment: can we solve without multiplier method.because this question of a class which is not taught this method. some other method please using single variable calculus

Comment: Yes, you can. But it reduces to the same thing. Let's use $z=k-x-y$. Then what you want to minimize is $xy+x(k-x-y)+y(k-x-y)$. Take the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, set them to $0$ and you get $x+y=2k/3$ or $z=k/3$. You will also get $x=y=z$. Plug it into the equation for the area, and you get the answer

Comment: we still have two variables

Comment: That's why you have two derivatives, and both need to be zero. Take the derivative with respect to $x$ and you get $y+k-2x-y-y=0$ and similarly, taking the derivative with respect to $y$ you get $x+-x+k-x-2y=0$. Adding these equations yield $3(x+y)=2k$, meaning $z=k/3$.

Answer (score 0):

The two apiled rectangles leave an area associated to three similar triangles. The rectangles will have maximum area when the three similar triangles are equal

or ressuming

$$
\frac 12 b\cdot h = 12 \Rightarrow b\cdot h = 24\\
3\frac 12 \left(\frac b3\cdot\frac h3\right) = 4
$$

so the maximum area is $12-4 = 8$

NOTE

The problem is the same depending on the number of apiled squares. In the case of $n$ we have the maximum squares area is given by $12 - n\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{b}{n}\frac{h}{n}\right) = 12-\frac{12}{n}$ for $n = 1, 2,\cdots$

To show the necessity of the equality between the small excess triangles think on the problem depicted in the included picture.

[image]

Comment: from where and how are tou getting b/3, h/3?

Comment: @maveric The triangles which represent the lateral area difference for each quadrilateral and also the summit triangle, are both similar to the big one with area  $12$ If both three are equal located at one side one below the other, being equal their dimensions are proportional by $\frac 13$. Note that their height should sum $h$ so each has $\frac h3$ and by similitude $\frac b3$ also.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Could you please explain the meaning of out of blue? Thanks. It can be reasoned as to show that the condition of three equal triangles is necessary.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I would try to include as a note in my answer.  I will fight with the idiomatic frontiers because I am not  english parlant.

Comment: I got it: We see three small right triangles along $AB$ and three along $AC$. In order to minimize the total area of these six triangles we argue as follows: The sum of the areas of the three triangles along $AB$ is proportional to the sum of the squares of their hypotenuses. This sum is minimal iff the three hypotenuses all have the same length.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter This is a good argument too. My argument would be by reductio ad absurdum.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a perpendicular from $A$ to the base, and consider the "right half" $S$ of the triangle, whereby we may assume $A=(0,1)$, $C=(1,0)$, $Q_1=(x,0)$, $\>0\leq x\leq1$.
If there were just one rectangle we would have to maximize $x(1-x)$, leading to $x={1\over2}$. For two rectangles we therefore have to maximize
$$f(x):=x(1-x)+\left({x\over2}\right)^2=x-{3\over4}x^2\ .$$
The maximum is at $x={2\over3}$ with $f\left({2\over3}\right)={1\over3}$. It follows that 
$${{\rm area}_\max(R_1\cup R_2)\over{\rm area}(S)}={f\bigl({2\over3}\bigr)\over{1\over2}}={{1\over3}\over{1\over2}}={2\over3}\ ,$$
so that the answer to the question is ${2\over3}\cdot12=8$.